# Android data binding not shown

Tags: android, data-binding

I am trying to use data binding in my app, but nothing is shown.

This is what I did:

- I created an New Project with an Empty Activity.
- I added

  ```
  dataBinding {
      enabled = true
  }
  ```

  to my build.gradle

This is my activity_main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <data>
            <variable name="game" type="my.name.bar.Bar"/>
        </data>
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context="my.name.bar.MainActivity">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@{game.GetFoo()}"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </layout>
```

And this is my Bar class

```
    public class Bar {
        private String str;

        public Bar() {
            str = "Foo";
        }

        public String GetFoo() {
            return str;
        }
    }
```

But I am only getting a white screen. If I replace the binding with just "Hello World!" then everything works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm guessing that you forgot to bind the value. When you bind, did you use something like this? `ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main); binding.setGame(new Bar());`

Comment: Thanks! That is what I was missing! You can promote your comment as an answer, and also tell where to put this code (MainActivity.java).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(promoted from the comment)

You must bind the value. In your case, it is something like this:

```
ActivityMainBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.activity_main);
binding.setGame(new Bar());
```

Comment: ... in MainActivity.java.